# How do I change route onSubmit in a searchbar?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I have one input I will use to call an api and when I press "enter" I just want to push me into another route. I am using Next.js. My code:

```
<form onSubmit={() => { router.push('/search') }}>
  <input type="text" placeholder="test" />
</form>
```

the output of this is that the page refreshes without changing route. It prints to console if I do a log, but the route doesn't change.
What do you think I did wrong or I missed?

Comment: please do not post 'Thank you'; it is fluff and not needed.

Comment: Allright! thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Default behavior of *onSubmit* method of a form element is to refresh the page.
To avoid that you need to add `event.preventDefault()` in the submit method. This will stop the page refresh.

```
<form onSubmit={(event) => { event.preventDefault();router.push('/search') }}>
  <input type="text" placeholder="test" />
</form>
```

Comment: what if **event** is deprecated?

Comment: Currently event is not deprecated. I verified from Mozilla docs [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event). A lot of JS features and frameworks depend on **event**, so I believe it won't get deprecated soon

Comment: ok thank you! maybe it's the extension I have on VSCode, but it works!

Comment: @RafDor Hah! "What if event is deprecated?" so funny so funny